# Getting started on modeling magnetic field lines in C++

Tags: physics

I'm doing a project on creation magnetic field lines using C++. I've worked with the computational part of C++ (not really concerned with design or anything too fancy), but I'm having trouble "taking off" with creating magnetic field lines. I'm not sure how to model something involving a cross product

Lorenz force eqn: F = q(v x B)

I've looked into possible ways such as varying the step of the radius in relation to the field, but I also feel that I would need to find a way to vary the angle at which the field appears.

I just want to model a simple dipole magnet. I would generate points using C++, then save them as a txt file and plot them using gnu plot. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As GuyGreer suggests, you can start at a source and follow the field to the sink. A field line follows the vector of the field at every point, so ideally you would consider not just the direction of the field at the point but also the gradient of the field; otherwise you will need more points to obtain an accurate line.

An alternative method would be to draw a straight line from source to sink, and move along its length checking the field vector is aligned with the field line. Where it is not, break the line into two segments and move the centre point; in effect you are moving the line around to find the field line, and adding more line segments where it wiggles more. Ideally go with splines or some other curve.

You mention cross products. If you can obtain the value of a field vector at a point as a 3d vector, then its cross product with another vector is just the standard definition of a cross product:

```
// given vectors a and b with properties x, y and z representing the components
cross.x = a.y * b.z - a.z * b.y;
cross.y = a.z * b.x - a.x * b.z;
cross.z = a.x * b.y - a.y * b.z;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start like this:

For each field line you want to create, start with a charge (say an electron) near one pole and then solve the initial value system of differential equations (with say Runge-Kutta) until you reach the other pole.  This is one line.

Repeat using different starting points (near the one pole).

The initial value system of equations I'm talking about is:

**F** = q(**v** x **B**)

d **v** / dt = (q/m) (**v** x **B**)

Hopefully this is a good start. (I'm not going into detail for the RK method since you mention that you are familiar with the computational part, if you're not familiar with it it's quite popular so you should have no trouble googling it)